# Is there a difference between parchment paper for writing on and the type you use in cooking?

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I have tried searching this question many different ways but to no avail. My instinct and common sense say the processing is probably exactly the same but I would like to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Parchment paper for cooking is coated with silicone.  Therefore, most traditional writing implements would not even be able to leave a permanent mark on it.

In addition to the coating, at least one brand says it uses [additional manufacturing steps to strengthen its cooking parchment paper](https://www.chowhound.com/food-news/55408/whats-the-difference-between-parchment-paper-and-waxed-paper/):

> A spokesperson for Reynolds Consumer Products, says that the company’s
>   parchment paper is pressed into a sheet, then dipped into an acid
>   bath, washed, and “passed over a series of hot rotating drums that
>   realign the fibers and give the paper its strength,” before the
>   silicone coating is applied.